# Xamarin Form - How to open documents in uwp desktop application

Tags: windows-10-universal, xamarin.uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I want to open the documents like pdf, office , image, txt, rtf inside the uwp desktop application. is there any control in toolbox which open this type of documents ? :(
thanks in advance :)

Comment: You could open image text rtf with RichEditBox control. For pdf, please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712068/how-can-i-show-an-pdf-file-in-xamarin-pcl-uwp-that-is-outside-my-instal-folder/47747934#47747934).

Comment: i am tried for image [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/rich-edit-box) but it cant display an image    for image what value set ? editor.Document.LoadFromStream(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, randAccStream);

Comment: You could use `InsertImage` method  to insert image to `RichEditBox`, please refer this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51626963/7254781).

Comment: and for office,excel sheet,word, ?

Comment: You could use  [`DocumentFormat.OpenXml`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) nuget package. Open XML SDK provides tools for working with Office Word, Excel, and PowerPoint documents.

Comment: do you have any code sample because i just want to display files inside my uwp application

Comment: Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet#sample-code).

Comment: yes i am refereed this but on which control we should display this ??

Comment: You could use [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid) to display the parsed data.

Comment: which third party paid controls good for UWP application development ? where i can convert images in pdf even open any documents inside uwp application